# Sharing Screens Using Bluetooth

Tags: java, android

**I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe app that has a 2 players game play. But I'm stuck at the point on how can I share the two screens between the two phones. So now I'm able to connect the two phones using Bluetooth but now I cannot find any references that help me to show how do I share screens between two phones? **

Comment: You do not need to "share screens". You need to share game state (e.g., which squares in the grid have X's, O's, or are blank) and game events (e.g., what move the currently-active player chooses to make).

Comment: i have that idea in my mind that i would add a ID to all the cells and transfer the ID using bluetooth. I just dont know how am I able to do that and how can I tell the other phone that a game is being played. How would i create that one way chat?